# Adding a new, required table to a database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

Basically I have an existing users table, and I need to add a table for user metadata. When a new user is created we generate the default metadata, but for existing users this doesn't exist yet and we need it to.

Essentially add table, loop through users, and insert default data, something like this pseudo-code:

```
FOR EVERY user IN users
  INSERT INTO `meta_data` VALUES (
    'generate UUID',
    'users UUID from users table'
    '2014-12-29 22:57:55',
    '2015-01-01 01:39:37',
  );
```

I've dealt with a little bit of mysql but this would be my first any sort of sql script.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html If you provided full schema for both tables it would make a full answer possible.

Comment: What do you need exactly? The script to insert meta data into the table?

Comment: There's no need to process row by agonizing row (RBAR) using a script to fetch a row, and do an insert, fetch another row, do an insert. Where SQL shines is on operating on *sets* of data. Just write a SELECT statement that returns the rows you need to add, and turn that into an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, and just be done with it.

Comment: `INSERT ... SELECT` sounds like what I need. I will report back and make sure to mark the accepted answer once I can confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `INSERT` statement with a `SELECT` in place of the values:

```
INSERT INTO meta_data
SELECT UUID(), u.uuid, '2014-12-29 22:57:55', '2015-01-01 01:39:37'
FROM users AS u
```

If you need to do this after you start adding metadata for new users, you can filter them out:

```
INSERT INTO meta_data
SELECT UUID(), u.uid, '2014-12-29 22:57:55', '2015-01-01 01:39:37'
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN meta_data AS m ON u.uuid = m.users_uuid
WHERE m.users_uuid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like what I need. I will report back and make sure to mark the accepted answer once I can confirm.